# Postfix can send but not receive mails - Recipient address rejected

Tags: 14.04, server, email, postfix, mail

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 Server with Postfix 2.11.0 and 2.2.9

Since the last weekend my mailserver can only send emails but not receive them.
Any help is much appreciated! :-)

The Error in mail.log file say:

```
Sep 17 09:31:21 trinity postfix/smtpd[7786]: connect from outmail235.swisscom.com[193.222.81.235]
Sep 17 09:31:21 trinity postfix/smtpd[7786]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from outmail235.swisscom.com[193.222.81.235]: 550 5.1.1 <n0_ah@*masked*>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table; from=<*masked*@*masked*rants.ch> to=<n0_ah@*masked*> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail.swisscom.com>
Sep 17 09:31:21 trinity postfix/smtpd[7786]: disconnect from outmail235.swisscom.com[193.222.81.235]
```

And this is the output of postconf -nf:

```
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
disable_vrfy_command = yes
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
local_recipient_maps = $alias_maps $virtual_alias_maps
mailman_destination_recipient_limit = 1
mydestination = $myhostname localhost.$mydomain localhost
mydomain = roundedge.ch
myhostname = mail.roundedge.ch
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 1.2.3.4/32 5.9.194.36
postscreen_greet_action = enforce
relay_domains = $mydestination
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_client_new_tls_session_rate_limit = 10
smtpd_client_restrictions = check_client_access cidr:/etc/postfix/drop.cidr
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_multi_recipient_bounce
smtpd_delay_reject = no
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated,
    reject_non_fqdn_hostname, reject_invalid_hostname, permit
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining,
    reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
    permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, permit
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated,
    reject_non_fqdn_sender reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/private/startssl/sub.class2.server.ca.pem
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/private/wildecard/server.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/wildecard/server.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 0
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/virtual-mailman,
    proxy:ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap_virtual_aliases.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_mailbox_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_domains
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap_virtual_recipients.cf
virtual_transport = dovecot
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite honestly - error states quite clearly, where is the problem. 
In your virtual mailbox table.

It says that user hasn't been found there, hence incoming mail hasn't been accepted.

I see you're using ldap for virtual users/mailboxes and aliases records - so first of all check if you can connect to your ldap server and, if so - whether your ldap records are in proper order.

Comment: Thanks Jacek for your quick response. I checked all users that have mail and from my view anything seems fine. I created a new user in gosa (user admin panel) to see if the issue is fixed for new users. But why is ldap the issue if sending messages works from all users?

Comment: For sending you don't check mailboxes, you check them for receiving mails to find where exactly to drop the incoming message.

Comment: If users are still there - make sure postfix is able to successfully connect to ldap then, with details from your ldap_virtual_recipients.cf config.